# Cleaning Spotify cache with crontab

Tags: bash, cron, spotify

Spotify caches a lot of data (multiple GBs) so that it can more quickly load songs you've already played. This is pretty useless given the cost.
I've tried to clean the cache with `crontab` but it never seems to work for me. I've tried the following two commands:

```
0 5 * * * rm -rf "~/.cache/spotify/Data/*" >/dev/null 2>&1
0 5 * * * /bin/bash -c "rm -rf ~/.cache/spotify/Data/*"
```

Comment: What went wrong in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expected (don't use quotes around tilde `~` and `*` ) :

```
0 5 * * * /bin/rm -rf ~/.cache/spotify/Data/* >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Also, avoid to swipe to allow downloading songs if you don't want to, in Spotify UI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the cache of the application, you can directly enter the profile screen - settings - storage - clear cache.

for more details, you can refer to this article: [How to Clear Spotify Cache PC/Mac/Android/iPhone](https://www.tunelf.es/spotify-music/borrar-cache-de-spotify.html)